# How can I change my mod_rewrite rules to work in the parent directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an MVC app with index.php located in a /public subfolder.  Currently, I point Apache to the /public folder and use .htaccess in there to rewrite MVC requests to index.php.

Current Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Current .htaccess in /public:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Target Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Target .htaccess, but I can't get both the MVC and asset URLs to rewrite correctly:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public

# If it's a file/directory/symlink, serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Otherwise let's go MVC
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Example URLs:

```
domain.com/login (MVC URL, rewritten to public/index.php)
domain.com/assets/styles.css (non-MVC URL, rewritten to public/assets folder)
```

Comment: Your config would seem to imply you have `/var/www/html/public/public` - 2 nested `public` directories? "so I don't need to add `/public` in Apache" - not sure what you mean by this? You want to remove the 2nd "public" subdirectory? In your "new" `.htaccess` file you also changed the _way_ you are rewriting the URL? Any reason for that? "non-MVC URL, redirected to public/assets folder" - How exactly are you doing this? There's nothing in the code you posted. Presumably you don't literally mean "redirected"?

Comment: Thanks for reading, and sorry for confusion.  There's only one public folder containing index.php and /assets.  Correct, rewritten, not redirected.

Comment: The old rule wasn't working for asset URLs after I moved .htaccess.  The MVC URLs work, but the asset URLs are also being rewritten to index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are setting up a local development environment to simulate a more restrictive live server environment then...

> Not sure why you want to do this, as your current config (setting the `DocumentRoot` to `/public`) would seem to be the most desirable (and simple) setup.
>
> Setting the `DocumentRoot` to the parent directory and *rewriting* to the `/public` subdirectory instead is often a workaround when you are unable to change the `DocumentRoot`. This is ultimately more work and exposes the `/public` subdirectory, which now has to be blocked/redirected to prevent direct access.

Anyway, moving to a `/public` subdirectory in the public HTML space...

Having set the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html` there are two ways to accomplish this, with either 1 or 2 `.htaccess` files. (Although, this also raises another question... why are you using `.htaccess` when you have access to the server config? Although there can be perfectly valid reasons for this.)

#### Method#1 - Two `.htaccess` files

It is arguably easier to do this with two `.htaccess` files. One in the document root that rewrites all requests to the `/public` subdirectory and one in the `/public` subdirectory that rewrites requests to your MVC app, in much the same way you are doing already. The presence of the `/public/.htaccess` file also serves to prevent a rewrite loop.

For example:

```
# (1) /.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# (OPTIONAL) If you need to allow access to files/directories/symlinks
#            outside of the "public" directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
#RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all requests to the "/public" subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

```
# (2) /public/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# If "public" directory is requested directly then redirect to remove it
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

# Stop early if already rewritten to MVC
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Rewrite to MVC app, otherwise serve assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

#### Method#2 - One `.htaccess` file in the document root

Alternatively, you have just one `.htaccess` file in the document root.

For example:

```
# /.htaccess (only)

RewriteEngine On

# If "public" directory is requested directly then redirect to remove it
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^public(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Stop early if already rewritten to "public" directory
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]

# If it's a file/directory/symlink, serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite to assets in "public" directory if they exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule !^public/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# Otherwise rewrite request to the MVC app in "public" directory
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm assuming all your "assets" have file extensions of between 2 and 4 characters. An optimisation to the above is if all your "assets" are referenced by `/assets/...` then you could simply rewrite all these requests to `/public/assets/...` - no need for filesystem checks. For example:

```
# Rewrite to assets in "public" directory (unconditionally)
RewriteRule ^assets/ public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Although this would mean you cannot have routes in the MVC app that start `/assets/`. But you probably shouldn't anyway.

*Aside:* If you aren't serving directories directly (it's unusual to do so these days) then you don't need to check whether the request maps to a directory in the rewrite rules. Just allow it to pass to your MVC app and trigger a 404 (rather than a 403) - which could be preferable.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response.  I was trying to avoid changing the default Apache config in a new environment.  I've had issues with Mac resetting httpd.conf after major releases.  I also thought it made sense to include all of the necessary rewrite rules in the deployment package and save a config change, but maybe not.